# Startup error messages GridCreationSettings

Tags: warning-messages

I've looked for a solution, but couldn't find one. I've reinstalled,but still get the following two (related) messages on startup:

The specified setting for the option GridCreationSettings, Columns cannot be used

and

An option ("GridCreationSettingsColumns->Round[Null]") was encountered with a right‐hand side value out of the supported range for this option.

Thanks in advance for any solution(s).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please give some more information (OS, version of Mathematica). It could be that this question can only be answered by Wolfram Research if this is a software issue in which case the question risks being closed.

Comment: Anything in your `init.m` file? Relevant, I suppose: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridCreationSettings.html. There is no symbol `GridCreationSettingsColumns` in Mma. Is there a typo in the question?

Comment: So far I'm really only using the software for presentation/notes creating... I'm really just clicking "Insert slide", or "Add cell" or changing cell types, or adding a table for side by side layouts. I don't think i've tried to manually adjust any settings. Re possible typos in question, I copied the text direct from the error messages.

Comment: Are there a set of red dots to the left of the message or a blue circle with an 'i' to the right? These can be used to either show a stack trace or link to the message in the documentation, if present. It would help if you could give a set of steps which reliably reproduces the error, since most users don't routinely encounter it. Reinstalling will update the files in the global location where the app resides, but won't normally change a user's private settings, which is why checking, or temporarily deleting any init files for the kernel/frontend might help, as mentioned above.

Comment: No dots or blue circle.... gives options to "Quit" or "Continue Anyway" This is happening at startup. Nothing happened whilst I was making any changes to a doc.

Comment: The only suggestion I can offer is to rename all init.m files in your user directory whcih store your preferences (Mathematica will launch and create new ones) and see if that fixes the problem. Alternately, create a temporary new user account and try running it from there to see if the same problem occurs. If things work, then it's a corrupted file. You could also move/rename the Frontend caches, and check any log entries in your user directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. I first saw it on Mathematica 12.3.1 after running that for a few years. It persisted when I upgraded to 14.0.

Following the suggestion by user87932 in the comments above, I renamed all the init.m files in ~/Library/Mathematica/ . I restarted Mathematica and it had me sign in at the Wolfram Portal. Then it worked fine. The init.m files are back.